# Length of a Busy Period of an M/M/c queue with an initial length of k

Tags: queueing-theory

The expected length of a busy period in an M/M/1 queue is $\frac{1}{\mu - \lambda}$. I believe the time to empty a busy M/M/1 queue with a current line of k is $\frac{k}{\mu - \lambda}$. Does anyone know what the equivalent expression might be for a M/M/c queue with a current line of k? If I somewhat redefine the question as the first time there exists any open server as the renewal is it just $\frac{k}{c \mu - \lambda}$? As an additional question, does anyone know of an expression for the variance or moment generating function of the length of the busy period?

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, time to empty in a $M/M/1$ queue if initially it has $k$ customers is computed here  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3374291/562306

Comment: That's actually very helpful. As opposed to calculating the length of the queue directly, I had been using an expression for the number of customers served during a busy period, found in [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jps/2019/7398658/) then using an erlang distribution to govern the time taken to service n customers in a busy period. Thereby using a hypererlang distribution over countably infinite Erlang distributions.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue#Busy_period_of_server

Comment: I believe this refers to the period between a queue having k jobs in the system and k-1 jobs. What I'm interested in is going from k jobs in the system (k > c) to 0 jobs in the system. This corresponds to the concept of the delay cycle from citation 8 in the linked wikipedia article. It's just difficult for me to parse the article.